# Why does postAtTime not trigger at the right time when screen is turned off

Tags: android, timer, screen, delay

I have made a simple timer app which update a textview every second.
I want it to make a beep every 10th second for a total duration of 100 seconds.
Bascially this is how I have made it (very schematic):

```
static long second, ticker, uptimemilli;
onCreate() {
  second = ticker = 0;
  Handler mHandler = new Handler();
  uptimemilli = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
  mHandler.postAtTime(mUpdateTimeTask, uptimemilli+1000*ticker++);
}

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    if (second == 100)
      return;
    UpdateMyTextView(second++);
    if (second%10 == 0)
      PlayBeep();
    mHandler.postAtTime(mUpdateTimeTask, uptimemilli+1000*ticker++);
  }
};
```

This works well when the phone display is on. The TextView is updated every second and it gives a beep every 10th second. However, I want the app to make the beep sound every 10th second even if I turn the display off. The problem is that when I do that (by short click on the power button), the timer loop seems to go in slow motion. I get a beep sound maybe every 20-25 seconds. So the postAtTime does not appear to work when the screen is turned off. Does anybody know why and how can I make postAtTime to trigger at the time I specify even when the screen is turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is that when I do that (by short click on the power button), the timer loop seems to go in slow motion. I get a beep sound maybe every 20-25 seconds.

The only reason you are even getting that is because something else is causing the device to power back on every 20-25 seconds. Shortly after the screen goes dark, the CPU powers down, and your application will no longer run.

> So the postAtTime does not appear to work when the screen is turned off.

`postAtTime()` is working perfectly well. The device is simply in sleep mode.

> Does anybody know why

Because the device is in sleep mode.

> how can I make postAtTime to trigger at the time I specify even when the screen is turned off?

Stop the device from going into sleep mode, such as via `android:keepScreenOn`.

Comment: Thank you! A short follow-up question. Is AlarmManager the only way to make something to trigger at a specific time after the screen goes dark?

Comment: @Anders: "Is AlarmManager the only way to make something to trigger at a specific time after the screen goes dark?" -- it is certainly the most power-efficient way. Anything else will require you to keep the device powered on at all times (e.g., a `WakeLock`).